# jQuery Mobile Align Images on Header

Tags: css

I have three images on my header:

```
<style>

.align-right 
    { 
float:right; 
margin-right: 5px;
display:inline;
    }

.align-left { 
float:left; 
margin-right: 5px;
display:inline;
}

.align-center {
    margin-left: auto !important;  
    margin-right: auto !important;  
    width=70%;  
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="align-left"><img src="icon-settings.png"></div>
    <div class="align-center"><img src="logo_transp.png"></div>
    <div class="align-right"><img src="icon-settings.png"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

The two icon-settings images are aligned correctly to the margin of the page but I want to get the logo aligned in the center of the page. Currently it is left-aligned against the left icon-settings image.

**How do I get the logo centered between the two images?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/mhbb3nxz/).

```
.align-center {
    margin-left: auto !important;  
    margin-right: auto !important;  
      position: absolute;
    display:inline;   
    left: 50%;
}
```

> position: absolute; left: 50%;